# UIApplicationShortcutItem in Swift to support 3D touch

Tags: swift, ios9, 3dtouch

How to launch and navigate to a particular view controller using short cut items?

I am using UINavigationController in my app. The issue is when I click on the short cut items, I have to navigate directly to last view controller. In the last view controller, I will have Back button to navigate back to previous screens. Is this possible?

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: Bool -> Void) {
        let handledShortCutItem = handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem)

    completionHandler(handledShortCutItem)
}


func handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {
    var handled = false

    // Verify that the provided `shortcutItem`'s `type` is one handled by the application.
    guard ShortcutIdentifier(fullType: shortcutItem.type) != nil else { return false }

    guard let shortCutType = shortcutItem.type as String? else { return false }

    switch (shortCutType) {
    case ShortcutIdentifier.LastViewController.type:
        print("Inside Agent **********")
        **// Navigate to view controller**
        handled = true


        break

    default:
        break
    }
```